# php calls to ipinfo.io hanging up (for last two days)

Tags: php, ip

My logging function uses the IP address of the person accessing a server based php utility, to retrieve details about the IP, with this code snipit:

```
  $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
```

Results look like this (when it is working):

2013-12-12  11-59-42 , Cou: US, Sta: Washington, Cit: Bellingham, IP : 24.xx.xxx.224, 
  Loc: xx.68610000000001,-xxx.41040000000001, Org: ASxxxx Comcast Cable Communications, Inc., 
  Pho: xxx, HostName: xxx xxx.comcast.net

For the last two days it has hung up, before eventually dying.  The website also hangs when accessed through the browser, so I can't see how to contact them directly.

This has been a long used utility site, with lots of references here on stackoverflow and elsewhere.  Does anyone know if they have ceased functioning?  Or are they maybe blocking my server? Any ideas are welcome.  The logging of decoded IP addresses is VERY useful, and I hate to give it up.  Or alternatives?  (I tried hostip.info, but they lack most non US locations).

Thanks!

Pete A

Comment: You've probably been blacklisted by IP for abusing the service.

Comment: It my location the service is also down; looking up the website results in a 500-nginx error

Answer (score 0):

Download a ip list and don't use free API's as they are not reliable.